# Jquery switch text within a div element

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a good way to simply change the "Add to cart" to "Remove From cart" but keep all the button and link properties, on click with Jquery?

**HTML**

```
<div class = "checkout_icon"> <a href="#" class="button">Add to cart</a> </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.checkout_icon a ').on('click', function(e) {  

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
         //
    }else{
        $('.checkout_icon').html($('<div>').append($('Remove from Cart', '#div')).html());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('.checkout_icon a').text('Remove from Cart');
```

And inside the `click` event:

```
$('.checkout_icon a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    this.innerHTML = $this.hasClass('selected') ? 'Remove from Cart' 
                                                : 'Add to Cart';
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text()` method to get the work done..

```
$('.checkout_icon a ').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = this.innerHTML; //  OR   $(this).text(); 
    var currText = 'Remove from Cart'
    if (text.indexOf('Remove') > -1) {
        currText = 'Add from Cart'
    }
    this.innerHTML = currtext;// OR   $(this).text(currText)
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/qQ3C5/)**

Comment: you can use the DOM native function:`innerHTML` instead of `text`

Comment: +1, though I didn't like the `indexOf` check, it's too risky, you shouldn't rely on text.

Comment: @gdoron .. Thanks for the insight.. Will thing twice before I use that :)

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/okevem/1/edit)*

```
$('.checkout_icon a ').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent browser follow 'a' 
  
    $(this).text( $(this).hasClass('selected') ? 'Add to cart' : 'Remove from cart' );
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');     
});
```